# Are printer drivers still necessary?

Tags: drivers, printing, cups, printer

When adding a new printer in CUPS, one can either use a driver for the specific printer model, or use "driverless printing".  As far as I can understand, virtually every new printer now supports AirPrint, and should thus work with driverless printing from CUPS.

Furthermore, the printing documentation on the Debian Wiki (most of which is, as far as I can tell, also applicable to non-Debian systems using CUPS) seems to suggest that driverless printing is preferrable, and even that printer drivers will eventually not be supported in CUPS anymore.  See for instance the section [Driverless Printing](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemPrinting#Driverless_Printing).

Is there any reason it may still be necessary, or desirable, to use printer drivers?  In particular, when buying a new printer for use with Linux, is there any reason to worry about the availability (or lack thereof) of Linux drivers for that particular printer, or is it sufficient to check that it supports AirPrint?

Answer (score 0):

There are many companies that do not provide support for their printers, for instance the Canon G 2000 has no support under Linux for its scanner.

So there is still a long way to go. Buy and keep your drivers carefully.